# UniqueConstrait on a table not working in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Hibernate verstion is 3.x

Below is the table structure,

```
firstname | lastname | salary
-----------------------------------
firstname | lastname | 100
firstname | lastname | 500
firstname | lastname | 1000
```

Below is the java code,

```
@Entity
 @Table(name="TABLE_NAME",schema="SchemaName",
    uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"firstname","lastname"})})
```

Though I have mentioned the unique constraint on the tuples 'firstname' and 'lastname',
am still able to add rows with the same firstname and lastname values.

I thought, I would get `HibernateException` or otherwise and I won't be allowed to add
same firstname and lastname values for multiple rows. I don't have unique constraint
created at the database level. Its there just in the code.

Why am I able to add duplicate rows? Or my understanding of unique constraint is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html)?

It is only a hint to include a unique constraint in the generated DDL. It will not do anything at runtime. Basically you need to create the constraint at the database level.

Comment: Thanks. In my example, am performing Insert and Select operation(Addition to table and querying from the table). These are DML statements. Java Doc which you pointed to speaks more about DDL statements. So, am still not getting!

Comment: What isn't it you are getting? '@UniqueConstraint' is only used for DDL generation. In other words it will add a unique constraint to the databse (if you choose to use that DDL). The annotation doesn't do anything for you at runtime.

Comment: When I need to explicitly set the constraint in DB, what is the use of putting that constraint in the entity class if that is not going to do anything at runtime?

Comment: You can use the entities to (automatically) create your database ( DDL script) in that case you need to have that information.